# Showing which files that match a specific pattern have changed between git branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I want to merge two branches but before, I'd like to review the changes between the two branches on all files whose filename ends with `.twig`.

Is it possible, or should I use some bash-magic like `git diff --name-only branch1..branch2 | grep .twig` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the file names to git diff after a --, so:

git diff --name-only branch1..branch2 -- '*.twig'

Should do what you want.  I put *.twig in single quotes so the shell won't expand it.